# Itertuples() in Tkinter function reveals an AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'A'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, tkinter, tuples

Within a Tkinter function, I need to create the list named: 'value' extracting every 10 rows the value of dataframe column named: df['A'].

The following for-loop **works perfectly** out of a Tkinter function:

```
value = []; i = 0
for row in df.itertuples(): 
            i = 1 + i
            if i == 10: 
                value_app = row.A
                value.append(value_app)
                i=0
```

However within Tkinter function I have the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/anaconda/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "<ipython-input-1-38aed24ba6fc>", line 4174, in start
        dfcx = self.mg(a,b,c,d,e)
      File "<ipython-input-1-38aed24ba6fc>", line 4093, in mg
        value_app = r.A
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'A'
```

A similar for-loop structure is running in another part of the same Tkinter function and is executed without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column A is your first column you can do :

```
value_app = row[0]
```

I had the same problem and I think that it only sees it as regular arrays